# How to remove Jenkins zombie ec2 plugin workers without restart?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins v2.404
Orchestrator running in ubuntu 20.04 docker container
EC2 Plugin v2.0.7
Workers running Ubuntu 20.04

This Jenkins server has a high load and comes down every once in awhile.  It has a health check and spins back up, but worker nodes and the jobs that run on them get stuck and can't be deleted.

Most of the jobs are successfully terminated.  But the worker node stays up and says the job is still running and on-demand ec2 instances have to be terminated manually.
[Example Zombie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWrLm.png)

On reboot the zombie workers are cleaned up.  But this server is extremely high load and hard to find a downtime for at the moment, so I'd like for a solution without a restart.

Tried:

1. To remove nodes -> get's stuck in node is being removed state

- Of note: I was able to remove an on-prem (non-ec2 plugin instance) which was stuck in this state.

2. Abort job via api call -> job updates to abort status, node remains

Where is the worker node stored? Memory? Is there a way to force a cleanup of zombie workers?

In lieu of magic, are there any best practice suggestions for handling Jenkins crashes without this happening?  In lieu of that, I guess I'll just have to figure out a way to keep Jenkins from spazzing.